# Store and forward latency

Tags: switch

I have a question about store and forward in the following setup-up.

```
                       Store and Forward Mechanism
```

PC1 <-> Switch (in port) <-------------------------------------> Switch (out port) <-> PC2

```
       |                        switch                            |
```

The link speed between PC1 and Switch (in port) is 1Gbit/s.

The link speed between Switch (out port) and PC2 is 1Gbit/s.

I wonder what would be the delay to send a packet of size S from PC1 to PC2? Is it going to be (2 x S / 1Gbit) or (3 x S / 1Gbit) because of the store and forward?
Does (in principle) the store and forward mechanism "operate" at least at 1Gbit/s frequency?

Thanks,

Comment: It depends on the switch model. Many switches will do wire-speed switching. Most of the switching today is done in hardware (very fast ASICs). You will need to be specific on the switch model.

Comment: Assuming wire speed it sounds like a total delay of 3 x S/1Gb ... Correct?!

Comment: Nominally, wire speed means no delay, or the same delay as experienced by a wire of the same length. Since the switch doesn't use ethernet internally, it may be transferred faster from one switch port to another switch port than it could be on a point-to-point ethernet cable, with a net result of no apparent delay.

Comment: Aha ... So 2 x S/1Gbit + epsilon?! And epsilon depends on S as well?!

Comment: Wirespeed means the device can switch/route packets at the same rate that you can send over the medium. A device will naturally add a certain delay. It would be ludicrous to believe you could have the same delay as in a cable of the same length. Even with cut-through switching you need to wait for (preamble n stuff) + 6 bytes so you get the dst mac and then you need to do a lookup before you can send. While some would consider this negligible, it is measurably more than what a cable of similar length would introduce, on the order of single or tens of microseconds.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Internal switching delay will be down in the nanoseconds. Thus you're only looking at the time to receive the frame plus the time to transmit the frame. I.e. a hair over 2S when there's zero contention.

Comment: By contention you mean that on the "out port side" there are no available buffers? OR, the switch is busy doing store and forward for the other pairs of in/out ports as well?

Comment: Buffer space, cost-port matrix availability, pause frames, cpu load, etc.